# threeJS .lookAt looking the wrong way, inherited rotations

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am just trying to get   `this._mesh.skeleton.bones[ 5 ]`(location: the bend in the green thing coming from the hand) to point the same way as the helper yellow line

```
    _FindBubble() {
        const handPosition2world = new THREE.Vector3();
        this._anchor['LeftHandIndex1'].getWorldPosition(handPosition2world);
        const dir = handPosition2world;

// helper yellow line
const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00 });
const points = [];
points.push( new THREE.Vector3( handPosition2world.x, handPosition2world.y, handPosition2world.z ) );
points.push( new THREE.Vector3( this._bubble._components.BubbleModelController.averageOfVertices.x, this._bubble._components.BubbleModelController.averageOfVertices.y, this._bubble._components.BubbleModelController.averageOfVertices.z ) );
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );
const line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
this._scene.add( line );

        dir.sub(this._bubble._components.BubbleModelController.averageOfVertices);
        dir.normalize();
        return dir.negate();
    }


    _Updateanimation(timeInSeconds) {
        const dirToBubble = this._FindBubble();
        var dirToBubbleObj = new THREE.Object3D();
        dirToBubbleObj.lookAt(dirToBubble);

        this._mesh.skeleton.bones[ 5 ].quaternion.set(dirToBubbleObj.quaternion);
    }
```

photo with `this._mesh.skeleton.bones[ 5 ].quaternion.slerp(dirToBubbleObj.quaternion, 1)` instead of set, `.set(dirToBubbleObj.quaternion)` does not render any of the green tube from the hand after bone 5
[image: description]

changing _Updatedateanimation to

```
  _Updateanimation(timeInSeconds) {
        const dirToBubble = this._FindBubble();
        this._mesh.skeleton.bones[ 5 ].lookAt(dirToBubble);
  }
```

has given me this, which sort of feels like progress, i dont know why its different i thought i would do the same as the code above but it was just written cleaner

[image]
[image]
[image: running, hand up]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a bone of minimal length in place of 0 between the hand and the tube in the code below and make 1 -> 0 so there is not a funky bend at the start, i will update later when i get around to it but below gives the effect i was going for

```
  _Updateanimation(timeInSeconds) {
    this._mesh.skeleton.bones[ 0 ].lookAt(this._bubble._components.BubbleModelController.averageOfVertices);
    this._mesh.skeleton.bones[ 1 ].rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
  }
```

[image]